# How do I change recessed GU10 bulb?

Tags: electrical

I have a gu10 spotlight that needs a new bulb. But, i cant get the bulb to drop down far enough to grab the small rose thats its inserted into so I can twist it free.

Should I yank the cable in the hope that if its snagged it will come free, or is there another way?

Comment: A picture would help a great deal

Comment: The handyman's secret weapon -- duct tape!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a suction cup. It will allow you to push it in and twist. I've always just used one from around the house. I only have two gu10s in my house. I'm sure you could order one on Amazon that would be designed for the job.